# Back face as pure black with LWRP - Unity

Tags: unity, shaders

I need to use LWRP in my current project, and I was looking for a way to render the back face as pure black, no lights, no shadows, nothing, just pure black while the normal face would should the textures and the maps.

I know how to do it using the regular shaders, but it is possible to do using the LWRP shaders?

Answer (score 1):

Well... I kind of figured a way to do it, I think that this isn't optimized at all, but it works flawlessly.

In the inspector I added a second material to the object and I created a new shader using the "Is Front Face" and the "Branch" node to set the normal faces transparent and the "back faces" to show the color I wanted